# How to generate unique id per row by using row_number() over() in a large table Hive ql?

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

I am using `row_number()` `over()` in order to get a unique id per row of a table. The table is about 16m records.

However, `row_number() over()` is stuck in 999999 and after that does not increase the unique id.

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Could you please post the complete query, and the schema?

Comment: Hi Charles, I have tried. Doesn't look like it stuck at 999999.